# Javascript Date not giving tupdated value

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

here i was making a sample program in php.In which i included the java script and used the date but i am getting the same date every time.let have a look on the code.

```
<?php
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var time1=new Date();
            var time_stack=new Array();
            var time;
            $(this).mousemove(function(){
                time=time1.getSeconds();
                alert(time1);
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>we are on the main_session</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

now the problem is that when i move the mouse than i get an alert box popping out and the date which is being displayed is same all time.Please let me know the problem

Comment: You would not like to call `alert()` function `onmousemove` ;)
Better show this value to some `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(this).mousemove(function(){
                var time1=new Date();
                time=time1.getSeconds();
                alert(time);
            });
        });
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

Hi, You should assign value for `time1` variable in the `mousemove()` function. Use like this:

```
$(this).mousemove(function(){
    var time1 = new Date();
    var time_stack = new Array();
    var time;
    time = time1.getSeconds();
    alert(time1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because time1 is evaluated only once when the page loads, on every mouse event you just get the seconds from  when it was initialized

Answer (score 0):

The variable `time1` never changes, the `Date` object is the same, so you always get the same time ?

You have to either update the Date on each mousemove, or just get a new `Date` object :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>my app</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(this).mousemove(function(){
                var time1 = new Date();
                console.log( time1.getSeconds() );
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>we are on the main_session</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6KfEb/1/)

Comment: thanks adeneo....these are such samll things that made me mad in order  to find out

Comment: @user1334573 - no problem, dates in javascript can get really confusing sometimes

Answer (score 0):

The Date object your instancing isn't a stop watch that will get the current time when you call a method on it. You need to instances a new Date object in your event handler.

```
alert(new Date().getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a misprint:
`alert(time)`, not `time1` and try this:

```
$(this).mousemove(function(){
                var time1=new Date();
                time=time1.getSeconds();
                alert(time);
            });
```